# Certificate Error while running Selenium test cases in IE

Tags: selenium

I am trying to run my selenium test cases in IE,and am facing some issues

First, `element.click()` is not working sometimes. According to to my observation when I try to do something else while the script is running in my machine, it's not working, but I didn't face this kind of issue in Firefox and Chrome.

Second, there are some links in my application when I click on them another window will come up.  From my script, when I use the `click()` function it's not able to click on that link. This issue is not there in Firefox or Chrome.

Third, in my application I am getting Certificate Exception. To avoid that I used:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "browserdrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    web  = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    web.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    web.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    web.get(url);
    web.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
```

I have used the above code, it worked now and I am able to log in, but in my test cases there are cases where, when I click on a link it will navigate to another window. When I do this the other window is coming up again with certificate Exception. I am not able to run the rest of cases and resulting all the cases have failed.

I am not able to figure out the problem why these issues are occurring.
IE version am using is IE 11.0
selenium version am using is 2.39.0

Answer (score 0):

Never use `caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);` capability. If you are NOT able to open IE without this capability, then might be because of protected mode settings which should be set to the same value for all zones (either on or off) and also browser zoom level should be 100%. Read more here : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Comment: I have changed the settings and Removed caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true); but still am facing the certificate issue, when i switch to other window clicking the link in application am still getting that certificate exception

Comment: After switching to new window, handle certificate exception by the code you pasted: `web.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");` and then start working on the elements on that new window.